# Firefox displaying image colours incorrectly

Tags: firefox, png, gimp

I have a website that incorporates a logo in to the header. This logo has a background that is the same colour as the background of the header, yet in Firefox the colour is different.

I can find various articles alluding that the 'colour profile' being the culprit, but I cannot find out how to fix this issue.

Quite why anyone would think that changing the colour of an image is the way forward I don't know, but it looks very poor, so I'd be grateful for some suggestions on how to fix this.

To create the original image I used GIMP, and it has been exported as a PNG.

Here is a section of the header so that you can visually see what I mean -
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not provide the original image, I have to make an educated guess:
Your image most likely has a (broken, incorrect) [color profile embedded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/ICC_color_correction_in_Firefox). Fix or remove the color profile and you should be good. See the documentation of your favorite tool on how to do that.

Comment: The current colour profile of the image is sRGB. I cannot see a way of removing the profile, and the GIMP docs seem to suggest that this is the default. You suggest that the colour profile may have become corrupt, so I created a new image of the same size, and then copied and pasted the old image. I exported this over the old image, reloaded my page, and it was fine. So thanks, I was unaware a colour profile could become corrupt!

Answer (score 1):

You should use some tool like [tweakpng](http://entropymine.com/jason/tweakpng/)  to check if the PNG has a color profile, and remove it.

Comment: Thanks for the link. No doubt it'll become more useful as I start to do more work with graphics and logos.